# Segoe MDL2 Assets in HTML page does not see in Windows 7

Tags: windows-10-iot-core

I've made a simple website in HTML/CSS for a private local network at home and all the PCs and phones are Windows10. Now a friend of mine, arrived at home with his beautiful laptop with mounted on Windows 7 and... his Chrome does not show all the symbols in my pages! There are only some rectangles. 
The pages are hosted in a simple webserver on Raspberry PI2 with Windows 10 IoT Core according this posts:

http://bitaware.altervista.org/little-webserver-raspberry-pi/

How can I solve it?

Thanx a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/style/segoe-ui-symbol-font):

> To obtain Segoe MDL2 Assets, you must install Windows 10.

So your icons won't show up on older versions of Windows or on Android, iOS, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can also download zip for MAc and install fonts manually on older versions of Windows. Take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/segoe-ui-symbol-font#how-do-i-get-this-font